# Detecting a cycle in an undirected graph and printing the vertices if there is a cycle, printing no cycle otherwise

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Problem: Find an O(E + V) time algorithm that outputs the vertices of a cycle of G, if it exists. If G has no cycles, the algorithm outputs no cycle. So if there is a cycle 1, ... 3, 1, it would print 1, ..., 3, 1.

So I was thinking of doing a BFS, and if the currently examined vertex's neighbor v has been visited prior, then there is a cycle. However, I am not sure how I might go about tracking the vertices in order to print. I believe I would have to view the BFS-Tree, but unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got it!

The usual way to record the cycle is to mark the *predecessor* or *parent* of each node: that is, the node from which it was first visited. Then you can follow the trail of parents to print out the cycle.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: I have a question however. If I were to trace through the predecessors, what if the cycle contains the source vertex of the BFS? Then I am unable to continue printing out this cycle. @Draconis

Comment: @RichardWeng You'd have to go upward through the predecessors from both "endpoints" (the vertex you were analyzing when you discovered the cycle, and the vertex that revealed the cycle by being already visited) and find where the two converge.